# How do i access a dictionary value in a django template?

Tags: django, dictionary, django-templates

Here's the code

```
def index(request):
    highest_bids = {}
    for listing in Listing.objects.all():
        highest_bids[listing.id] = listing.product_bids.order_by('bid').last()
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
        "listings" : Listing.objects.all(),
        "highest_bids" : highest_bids
    })
```

Now how do I access value of a key inside **highest_bids** from **index.html**?

```
   <div class="price">Bid: ${{highest_bids[listing.id]}}.00</div>
```

I tried this but it keeps giving me this error:
`TemplateSyntaxError at / Could not parse the remainder: '[listing.id]' from 'highest_bids[listing.id]'`

How do I correctly do it?

Comment: You can not subscript in Django templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not subscript in Django templates. What you can do is just add an attribute:

```
def index(request):
    queryset = Listing.objects.all()
    for listing in queryset:
        listing.highest_bid = listing.product_bids.latest('bid')

    return render(
        request,
        'auctions/index.html',
        {
            'listings': queryset,
        },
    )
```

and thus render with:

```
{{ listing.highest_bid }}
```

Comment: Just a question, Will doing this add the attribute "highest_bid" to the Listings table that is stored in the database or will it just create a new queryset with the additional attribute "highest_bid"? I am just learning about sqlite so i dont know much about it

Comment: @Virtual: it will not store anything in the table, we just add these to the objects in memory. So we add an attribute to the objects in memory, after the view, the data is "gone".